# How can I monitor a particular file and trigger an AWS Lambda function in AWS EFS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

I have a Mainframe(MF) that drops a file at my EFS location (say /temp/mf directory, filename test.txt)

I want a file trigger (could be any AWS service) to detect the file (test.txt), whenever it's available and not been changed for say 30 seconds to ensure the MF has finished writing to the file, and then fire the lambda function.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

EFS and lambda are a tricky match.  As EFS is essentially an NFS service, it requires a server to mount the EFS share in order to access the files contained within.

If you wanted to make this work, you would need a server (i.e. an EC2 instance) to mount the EFS share.  Logic on that server would then need to monitor the file as you specify.

Your server could then invoke your lambda once the file was ready.  You have several options for that:

1. Server pushes file to web service API that is backed by lambda
2. Server pushes file to S3, lambda driven from S3 event
3. Server sends event to lambda (SNS or SQS). Event either includes file or server makes file available to lambda (e.g. via an HTTP server)

Honestly, though, you might be better off contemplating a different architecture.  Alternatives include:

1. If logic on the MF can handle the monitoring and push the file into S3 (or even SNS/SQS if the file is small or you can break up the data), your lambda can take it straight from there (#2 above)
2. If you're stuck with EFS, you need that EC2 instance regardless, so you might as well do your processing on that